# Firebase deploy failing. Stuck in retry loop...No clear errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Firebase functions using firebase-cli.
Running `npm run deploy`
OR
`firebase deploy --only functions`
OR
`firebase deploy --only functions:<function_name>`

Presented with errors below since 8th Nov.

**Desired Outcome:**
Functions deployed to cloud function for API to run.

**Actual Outcome:**
Errors below.

Cloud functions doesn't have a source. I have not removed this.
[image]

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "build": "npm run lint && tsc",
    "serve": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='../apixel.json' tsc -w | firebase serve --only functions:apixel",
    "dev": "tsc && ts-node-dev --poll | firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json | firebase emulators:start --import=./firestore_emulator_data",
    "dev:public": "tsc -w | firebase emulators:start --import=./ --export-on-exit",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions --debug",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "ts-mocha --reporter spec --require @babel/register",
    "test:watch": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='apixel-test.json' ts-mocha -w --reporter spec --require @babel/register --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.16.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.22.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "raw-body": "^2.4.1",
    "stripe": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.5",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "mocha": "^8.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Error log in question, with error message:

```js
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:44.892Z] [update-us-central1-apixel] Retrying task index 0
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:44.893Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YXBpeGVsL3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL2FwaXhlbC83d0xjYXdFV1hoVQ [none]
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.106Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YXBpeGVsL3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL2FwaXhlbC83d0xjYXdFV1hoVQ 200
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.106Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YXBpeGVsL3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL2FwaXhlbC83d0xjYXdFV1hoVQ {"name":"operations/YXBpeGVsL3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL2FwaXhlbC83d0xjYXdFV1hoVQ","metadata":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.OperationMetadataV1","target":"projects/apixel/locations/us-central1/functions/apixel","type":"UPDATE_FUNCTION","request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunction","name":"projects/apixel/locations/us-central1/functions/apixel","httpsTrigger":{},"status":"ACTIVE","entryPoint":"apixel","timeout":"60s","availableMemoryMb":256,"serviceAccountEmail":"apixel@appspot.gserviceaccount.com","updateTime":"2021-11-08T16:02:29.520Z","versionId":"234","labels":{"deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-b18b3715-9660-4fb7-a7b8-0a1fd30f6b4d/1b212db4-33e0-490b-b29d-a73b6a788d2f.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-387443608081@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1637595054&Signature=n5%2BhACgxxSfSRofHnqUSehE4eu74RxAfeDUGBbnVWt%2Bb%2F0ZTmug0ufJXGIydBOmE2IB%2FHFWSsGhmxtorM9O2M0VcRz2NUk2bsD0WYx21VXKYsYhByKKBYb%2BjfG%2FH%2B2bEWcik7kqtXqXt%2BxjEd3Ahiw7nOLVISnS9xN6%2FrEklqCZkrPGDLFwdg3pnvVR18MwaQgl2CX%2FKA7nBANQPORpnQq7gS7lJJTD6S29iuF8g12EnvKMjtjbypgAXt1tdIiMzSBeecz5iJYnpmmQdTZHa00ns9c46C6UNzHqN8zDiiQL3sGBYgRBiaeO4%2BvQsBlbZ3OgRNyDxbI%2FoMsl8wa3bgg%3D%3D","environmentVariables":{"FIREBASE_CONFIG":"{\"projectId\":\"apixel\",\"databaseURL\":\"https://apixel.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"apixel.appspot.com\",\"locationId\":\"europe-west\"}","GCLOUD_PROJECT":"apixel"},"runtime":"nodejs14","ingressSettings":"ALLOW_ALL","buildId":"fd9ce520-84eb-49a8-9bcd-97985151058a","buildName":"projects/387443608081/locations/us-central1/builds/fd9ce520-84eb-49a8-9bcd-97985151058a"},"versionId":"270","updateTime":"2021-11-22T15:02:42Z","buildId":"5ecabdb0-ff0f-4cf9-abf7-a98a283f02ac","sourceToken":"b94a94e4-a0ea-4c12-9606-d776f8f56b42","buildName":"projects/387443608081/locations/us-central1/builds/5ecabdb0-ff0f-4cf9-abf7-a98a283f02ac"},"done":true,"error":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."}}
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.107Z] Got source token b94a94e4-a0ea-4c12-9606-d776f8f56b42 for region us-central1
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.110Z] Total Function Deployment time: 109152
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.110Z] 1 Functions Deployed
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.110Z] 1 Functions Errored
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.110Z] 0 Function Deployments Aborted
[debug] [2021-11-22T15:02:45.110Z] Average Function Deployment time: 109151
[info]
```

Specifically:

```js
"error":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."
```

Any help is appreciated, happy to edit question.

Comment: Error states `Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.` You sure there's no problem with the code?

Comment: Emulators launch, Postman works locally with all endpoints, serves fine. No linting errors, no build errors.
 I have read that too many endpoints through one function `export const apixel = functions.https.onRequest(app);
`delivery point could cause issue, but I am attempting to run that now.

Comment: I don't know any other way to find any errors related to code. If it works locally and all endpoints return succesfully and as intended, what else is there to test?

Comment: As @BEAGLE mentioned, this message is due to an error in your code. Share the code you are using in order to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: was a solution ever found to this? I've narrowed it down to the length of a typescript filename. i.e. myfunction.ts works, myfunctionTwo.ts fails. Literally the length of the file name breaks the build!